# TableLayout: Align RadioButtons with columns above

Tags: android-layout

I have a TableLayout with two columns. The TextViews and EditTexts are aligned nicely. How can I get the RadioButtons to align with the TextViews and EditTexts?

```
<TableLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
        <TextView
            android:text="Column 1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Column 2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/editText3" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/editText4" />
    </TableRow>
    <RadioGroup
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3">
            <RadioButton
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Radio Button 1"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1" />
            <RadioButton
                android:text="Radio Button 2"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />
        </TableRow>
    </RadioGroup>
</TableLayout>
```

This is what it looks like

[image]

I would like RadioButton2 to be aligned with Column2

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I took out the last **table row** and added **layout weights** to each button

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeP9H.png

```
<TableLayout
    android:minWidth="25dp"
    android:minHeight="25dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1">

        <TextView
            android:text="Column 1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Column 2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2">

        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/editText3" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/editText4" />

    </TableRow>

            <RadioGroup
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1">

            <RadioButton
                android:checked="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Radio Button 1"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1" />
            <RadioButton
                android:text="Radio Button 2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />

            </RadioGroup>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

*You need to add **`android:layout_marginLeft`** for the right radio button -*

[image]

**Example -**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TableLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
        <TextView
            android:text="Column 1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Column 2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/editText3" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/editText4" />
    </TableRow>
    <RadioGroup
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3">
            <RadioButton
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Radio Button 1"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1" />
            <RadioButton
                android:text="Radio Button 2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />
        </TableRow>
    </RadioGroup>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```